# I am using Two libraries on one page and i am getting a conflict only one works at a time

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have two jquery items on one page (slider and vticker) and only one will work at a time? how can I get them to work together? i have added a link to my html below. I am new to jquery help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including your JavaScript libraries and plugins in the completely wrong way. Please upload the needed JavaSript Plugins and libraries in a separate folder in your website root. I mean the actual .js files, the one you downloaded from their authors.

For example call that folder 'scripts'.

Then just below your CSS inclusions, you'll include your JavaScript libraries with the following syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.vticker-min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/any_other_jqplugin_you_have.js"></script>
```

Currently you are making a link to a javascript file that does not exist, and additionally you are pasting the library plain code in your web page. That's not a good way to go.

Additionally, **always include jQuery library first**, before loading any other plugins that depend on it.

Keep in mind that it is probably acceptable to do the plugin initialization in the page it self, rather than a separate file, just like you did with your vTicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Do Plugin Initialization here.

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I made those adjustments then used this to single out the libraries var $j = jQuery.noConflict() and it worked! very helpful Pete!! Thanks! been working on that bug for some time now glad to get it fixed and move on.  :)

Comment: You just had the initialization wrong, glad it helped. This is very basic but important knowledge, try to remember it.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.pezigns.com/jquery.vticker-min.js` - 404 Not Found

^^ That would be your first problem.

Also note that your background image is nearly 2MB - this is excessively big and took a while to download! You should probably attempt to web optimise that.

Comment: GET http://www.pezigns.com/style.css 404 (Not Found) Pezi2.php:11
GET http://www.pezigns.com/jquery.vticker-min.js 404 (Not Found)

Take the "src" out of your <script> tags:
<script src="jquery.vticker-min.js" type="text/javascript">